# How to Remove or Edit View on setting menu in odoo version 10

Tags: odoo-10

[image]Actually, I want to edit view or remove in setting menu if possible. But I don't know how to do it. I try to find it in XML views for inherit but can't find.
If it is possible then how?
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find menuitem for `Settings/Dashboard` here : `addons/web_settings_dashboard/views/dashboard_views.xml`

and templates :`addons/web_settings_dashboard/static/src/xml/dashboard.xml`

and js file : `addons/web_settings_dashboard/static/src/js/dashboard.js`

If you want to hide menu `Dashboard`, just create a group named 'Hidden' and assign that menu into this group. And give users no access to this group.

Hope it will help you.